# AIR for iOS and displaying correct DPI images

Tags: ios, air, bitmap, dpi

How are you handling swapping the correct dpi bitmaps in your Adobe AIR base iOS apps? Do you have two versions of each image? Are you loading them in at runtime after detecting device resolution, or do you just embed them both and pick the appropriate resolution image as you go? Or do you just scale down your HiDPI images?

Answer (score 0):

I personally avoid scaling images for mobile devices especially in AIR. Embedding images will also bloat your memory usage and swf size which is not ideal given the limited resources. I separate my asset folder structure into 160, 240, 320 and query the application DPI at runtime before loading the assets.

Creating a simple class containing a static method like this could be useful.

```
 public static getAssetPath(name:String, ext:String):String {
    switch(DPI) {
        case 320:
             return "assets/320/" + name + ext;
        case 240:
             return "assets/240/" + name + ext;
        case 160:
             return "assets/160/" + name + ext;
        default:
             throw new Error("Unknown device DPI");
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I like this approach for when you're loading assets explicitly from the filesystem after app launch. Do you ever do it the other way, where you load an entire SWF containing your assets?

Comment: I must confess that I hadn't really considered this method. What would you say the advantages/disadvantages of this approach would be? My apps currently haven't required a massive number of assets and the loading of images, etc is built into the lifecycle of my objects so displaying before loading isn't a problem. I suppose it would increase the responsiveness of the app but perhaps bloat the memory usage and the executable size somewhat?

Comment: I'm just starting out, so I haven't yet done extensive testing. Certainly one big advantage is leveraging the visual layout potential of Flash, rather than relying on coordinates etc. I think it really depends on the kind of app you're doing. If it's a game, or something with a lot of dynamic parts, then your approach makes the most sense. In the context of what I'm doing, though, having 2 SWFs that are loaded at runtime seem to be the way I'm going to go.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Images (with or without text) i like using Vectors and create scaled Bitmaps at runtime when they dont have text in them. But using filters can become a problem when drawing vectors to Bitmap.

For images with Texts i use pre rendered images in my assets and load them accordingly at runtime. here is a great Artikle explaining best practices 
[Adobe- Multible screen sizes in AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/multiple-screen-sizes.html)

Comment: That works for vectors - sounds like a good solution. But my question was specifically about BitmapImages... how do you handle those?

Comment: Vectors are fairly slow in terms of rendering on mobile, though. I know on a project in the spring, I had to actually replace many of my vectors with bitmaps simply because it was increasing each frame's render time.

Comment: @JoshJanusch i only create scaled Bitmaps once from the Vectors at first app start, and the reuse those. constatly drawing them would cost performance as you said.

Comment: @TomAuger: In the second part of my answer i meant BitmapImages, should have been clearer, cous "images" as i said can mean anything. Depending of the amout of images I either just dowscale HiRes png's or load an swf with the right sizes at first launch of the app. Like I said, check out the link i added, it's go some nice examples. Loading swf's not included tho :(